# Script to initialise a MongoDB with an auto-Increment id

Tags: mongodb

I want to initialise a mongoDB with a script because I have some collection that I need to have values in the beginning So i followed the instructions: http://michelebusta.com/the-little-things-5-initialize-a-local-mongo-db/

I create a (.js) file I load it and it works,

```
db.serviceSpeedList.insert({
_id: 0,
name:"DHL", service:"DHL Ground"});

db.serviceSpeedList.insert({
_id: 1,
name:"DHL", service:"DHL Second Day Service"});

db.serviceSpeedList.insert({
_id: 2,
name:"DHL", service:"DHL Express"});

db.serviceSpeedList.insert({
_id: 3,
name:"DHL", service:"DHL International Express"});
```

the problem is that I have ID like  this:     "_id" : ObjectId("572b8601e6352994d76bb13e"), 
and I want to have an auto-increment Id (_id: 1), can you please Help me.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("572b8601e6352994d76bb139"),
"name" : "DHL",
"service" : "DHL Ground"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("572b8601e6352994d76bb13a"),
"name" : "DHL",
"service" : "DHL Second Day Service"
}
```

I used

```
var i= 0; 
db.serviceSpeedList.insert({ "_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Ground"}); 
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }) 
db.serviceSpeedList.insert({"_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Second Day Service"}); 
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

When I use it in the shell separately it works but when i put it in a script and use load ("D:\initMongo.js"); it doesn't work :( please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to perform an auto increment sequence in your mongodb database to do so. Complete exemple can be found : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: thank you for replying, i tried to use this, but when I put all this in the script and use : 
load ("D:\initMongo.js"); it doesn't work, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot @jearfevre it works finally with var i= 0; , I did a mistake when I whrite the script 
thank you again :)

Comment: no problem ^^ .

another thing please, can I use this method to initialise a mongodb on a server?

Comment: you are working in your dev env. If you want to have the same configuration on a production server you can either redo the same stuff manually or simply perform a mongo import / export (in order to copy all db to another). Suggest you go with import/export, it's a better approach

Comment: Can you please give me a small exemple with the import, I found something you talk about this??: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: please start a new sof question, since this will be another subject. I will help you over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set _id as any other property, if you have a js file, consider use a `var i = 0;` and increment that in each insert statement.

```
db.serviceSpeedList.insert({ "_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Ground"});
db.serviceSpeedList.insert({"_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Second Day Service"});
```

Just follow the flow

```
> var i = 0;
> db.serviceSpeedList.insert({ "_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Ground"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.serviceSpeedList.findOne()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "DHL", "service" : "DHL Ground" }
> db.serviceSpeedList.insert({"_id" : i++, name:"DHL", service:"DHL Second Day S
ervice"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.serviceSpeedList.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "DHL", "service" : "DHL Ground" }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "DHL", "service" : "DHL Second Day Service" }
>
```

Comment: instead of set the value of the id as a number, use a javascript variable that increase anytime you make the insert statement

Comment: Thanks a lot @Koitoer it works, :) 
just another question please, can I use this script with mongodb in server?